# Implementing a Map of String to Int in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, dictionary, int

I'm looking to use a map to map a string to an integer value but allowing the int to be manipulated within the map.

E.g.

```
var Map : map<string, int>;

Map["foo"] = 5;
Map["foo"] = Map["foo"] * 5;
Map["bar"] = 10;
Map["baz"] = Map["foo"] + Map["bar"];
```

I've seen other questions using objects for the purpose, but this seems to result in errors when mapping anything other than strings to strings, or doing anything other than setting and receiving data.

Comment: You can use Objects in JS, which is basically an equivalent of Java "map" string to *Everything*.

Comment: "Anything other than setting and receiving data" -- considering that's all a data structure does, what would "other" be?

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
var Map : map<string, int>;
```

Ain't valid JavaScript syntax. JavaScript isn't strongly typed.

You probably just want to use a object:

```
var Map = {};
```

Then you can perform the calculations you posted in your question just fine:

```
Map["foo"] = 5;
Map["foo"] = Map["foo"] * 5;
Map["bar"] = 10;
Map["baz"] = Map["foo"] + Map["bar"];

console.log(Map);
// Object {foo: 25, bar: 10, baz: 35}
```